# OBDC Error 0A000 when selecting a postgresql data table in Power BI

Tags: postgresql, odbc, powerbi

I have managed to connect postgresql to Power Bi following this article: http://niftit.com/connecting-power-bi-to-postgresql/

But I receive this error message below when I try to select the table of interest:

> DataSource:Error: ODBC:ERROR [0A000] ERROR: cross-database references are not implemented: “db.schema.table”;
>
> Error while executing the query
>
> Details:
>
> DataSourceKind=Odbc
>
> DataSourcePath=dsn=db
>
> OdbcErrors=Table

I looked into this article: https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Cross-Database-References-are-not-Implemented for a solution, but I don't know how to implement that solution in Power Bi.

Anyone else come across this issue and have a solution?

I will try to connect to postgresql database with the Npgsql GAC Installation instead (https://levlaz.org/using-microsoft-powerbi-with-postgresql/). I'm working on this now but I don't believe that's the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you found any solution to this?